# How to aggregate results on a common property value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of persons with a `group` property. Group value is a random string, which I don't know when I make my query. Some persons `group` values will possibly be the same.

I want to write a query to retrieve only one person per group (which person is returned in the group is non relevant for the moment).

I suppose I have to write some kind of aggregation. But I only read about examples aggregating on known values... Instead I need to aggregate on unknown values...

My schema is something like:

```
const schemaPersons = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  group: {
    type: String,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write aggregation query using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage:

- `$group` stage, group by `group` field, and get only first person's root document in `person` field

```
Persons.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$group",
      person: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qkSkXLdfT4F)